# Hadoop snapshot query - deletion & metadata information

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, snapshot

I was doing some research on Hadoop snapshot; creation, deletion, etc. I've some queries:

1. When I do the snapshot of a data on the disk, is the snapshot created only of that particular file/directory or all the copies present (assuming the replication factor to be 3)?
2. The snapshot records the block size and file location of the file/directory it executed. Other than the `.snapshot` directory, I couldn't locate or find the metadata information on the machine. Anyone has any information how to view this metadata information?
3. Also, the Apache wiki for HDFS snapshot mentions that a snapshot directory cannot be deleted. However, I was able to delete the `.snapshot` directory created. It didn't have any parent or descendant snapshot directory/file.

Anyone got any insights on this?

Comment: It looks like three separate questions and all three are missing the steps to reproduce, which version you're using, which OS, which Java vendor and version etc.

Comment: Although I do get your comment but I'm not aware that the hadoop snapshot depends upon OS & Java vendor. If it's the Hadoop framework you're referring to then I'm using HDP 1.6 with Oracle Java 7. The OS underlying is Centos 6.5

Comment: The first 2 questions are still intact, no solution yet. I was working on third one and encountered a shocking thing.
a) If we delete a file, the snapshot for which is created already, and we remove it from .Trash as well. This deletion actually shows the file is deleted. I compared the disk usage for the folder as well and confirmed that the size got reduced by the amount of the size of the deleted file.

b) However, when I see the files in the .snapshot directory, I cud c all of 'em (even the deleted one). And adding the individual file sizes of snapshots gets the total size b4 deletion.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comment above??

Answer (score 0):

1.When I do the snapshot of a data on the disk, is the snapshot created only of that particular file/directory or all the copies present (assuming the replication factor to be 3)?
- As per my info it remains the same, if HDFS RF is 3 - same remains for snapshots as well

2.The snapshot records the block size and file location of the file/directory it executed. Other than the .snapshot directory, I couldn't locate or find the metadata information on the machine. Anyone has any information how to view this metadata information?
- Not sure for now

3.Also, the Apache wiki for HDFS snapshot mentions that a snapshot directory cannot be deleted. However, I was able to delete the .snapshot directory created. It didn't have any parent or descendant snapshot directory/file. 
- It does not mean you have to delete the snapshot. By this statement it means you can't delete the HDFS directory on which snapshot is created (snapshots can be deleted/removed anytime)